# CKEditor ASP.NET WebForms Upload Not Working

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ckeditor

CKEDITOR 4.6.1

I tried a lot but it does not appear in the editor.

upload.ashx

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpPostedFile uploads = context.Request.Files["upload"];
        string CKEditorFuncNum = context.Request["CKEditorFuncNum"];
        string file = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploads.FileName);
        uploads.SaveAs(context.Server.MapPath(".") + "\\photo\\" + file);
        string url = "/photo/" + file;
        context.Response.Write("<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(" + CKEditorFuncNum + ", \"" + url + "\");</script>");
        context.Response.End();
    }
```

JavaScript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                CKEDITOR.replace('<%=CKEditorControl1.ClientID %>', { filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/Upload.ashx' }); veriyoruz
            });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditorControl1" BasePath="~/ckeditor/" runat="server"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

Comment: Is there any error in browser console ?

Comment: " Uncaught The editor instance "CKEditorControl1" is already attached to the provided element. "

Comment: config.extraPlugins = 'uploadimage';
    config.uploadUrl = '/upload.ashx';

Error has gone but it still does not show

Comment: your are mixing the version 4 syntax with the old version of ckeditor api. Please replace your server side editor control with html control.

Comment: I apologize, I do not quite understand what you mean. Could you tell me by code?

Comment: Please refer this documentation http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide